# Forgotten Password -cant change

Tags: password-recovery

I found my laptop from 6 years ago that my partner installed your operating system on. I have no idea what the password is. I have attempted to change it in recovery but when I try to type in a new password it wont let my type anything. I can press enter but it continues to say; 'Authentication token manipulation error' and ' password unchanged'.

I am not amazingly tech savvy, i know how to find and fix alot of problems but this type of stuff... ive done everything I could think of.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why not just overwrite everything with a fresh install? Are you trying to recover some files or just wanting to make use of the old laptop?

Comment: On that laptop we will not have an Ubuntu release greater than 10.04. This release is no longer supported. I recommend you re-install with a newer release. On "Upgrade Ubuntu 10.04 to ..." personal data will be kept if they were not encrypted and you will be able to create a new user with your own password.